# Terraform ip configuration not found error

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting this error when I deploy below main.tf script. Can you please help me understand what is messed up here? I am learning Terraform and not very good at it yet.

main.tf:

```
# description
#
# variables.tf: This file holds the values of the variables used in the template.
# output.tf: This file describes the settings that display after deployment.
# main.tf: This file contains the code of the infrastructure that we are deploying.
#
# created by Rajeev 6/8/2021
#

# basic setup
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
  client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
  client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
}

# step-1: create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "project1" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-rg"
  location = "${var.location}"
  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step-2: create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "project1" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/22"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step-2: create virtual subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "project1" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.project1.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

# step-3: create network security group
# refer: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/network-security-group/azurerm/latest
# refer https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "project1" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-netSecGrp"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  # source_address_prefix = ["10.0.0.0/22"]  #was giving err

  # rule to allow from only within subnet, covers ssh.
  security_rule {
    name                       = "inboundAccess"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "10.0.0.0/24"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  
  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step 4: defining pulic IP
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "project1" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-pub-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
  sku                 = "Basic"
  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step 5: defining Net Intfc.
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "project1" {
  count               = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
  name                = "${var.prefix}${count.index}-nic"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.project1.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}


# step 6: create load balancer
resource "azurerm_lb" "project1" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-lb"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "${var.prefix}-LbPublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.project1.id
  }

  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step 6: part 2
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "project1" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.project1.id
  name            = "${var.prefix}-BackEndAddressPool"
}

# step 6: part 3
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
  count               = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = "${var.prefix}${count.index}-nic-lb-pool-cfg"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.project1.id
}

# step 7: create virtual machine availability set
resource "azurerm_availability_set" "project1" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-avset"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name

  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step 8: build packer image using server.json

# step 9: create VMs using packer image. 1 VM
#
# sub-step-1: create a reference to the Packer image:
data "azurerm_image" "PackerImage" {
  name                = "myPackerImage"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
}
#
# sub-step-2: build VM based on above ref.
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "project1" {
  count             = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
      #refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#conditionals
  name                            = "${var.prefix}${count.index}-vm"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location
  size                            = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  admin_username                  = var.username      #value at runtime
  admin_password                  = var.password
  disable_password_authentication = false
  availability_set_id             = azurerm_availability_set.project1.id
  network_interface_ids           = [
    azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].id,
  ]

  source_image_id = data.azurerm_image.PackerImage.id

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${var.prefix}${count.index}-OSdisk"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}

# step 10: creat emanaged disk
# refer: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/managed_disk
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "project1" {
  count                = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
  name                 = "${var.prefix}${count.index}-mDisk"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.project1.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.project1.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "1"

  tags = {
    ND = "1"
  }
}
```

The error you see here did not come when i ran "$ terraform plan -out solution.plan"

**output:**

```
$ terraform apply "solution.plan"
azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[2]: Creating...
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[2]: Creating...
azurerm_network_security_group.project1: Creating...
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Creating...
azurerm_lb.project1: Modifying... [id=/subscriptions/4938xxxxxxx-4edd-8xxxxxxxf78e/resourceGroups/nanod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/nanod-lb]
azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[0]: Creating...
azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[1]: Creating...
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[0]: Creating...
azurerm_lb.project1: Modifications complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/4938xxxxxxx-4edd-8xxxxxxxf78e/resourceGroups/nanod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/nanod-lb]
azurerm_network_security_group.project1: Creation complete after 5s [id=/subscriptions/4938xxxxxxx-4edd-8xxxxxxxf78e/resourceGroups/nanod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nanod-netSecGrp]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[2]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[2]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[2]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[2]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[0]: Creation complete after 48s [id=/subscriptions/4938xxxxxxx-4edd-8xxxxxxxf78e/resourceGroups/nanod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/nanod0-vm]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[2]: Creation complete after 48s [id=/subscriptions/4938xxxxxxx-4edd-8xxxxxxxf78e/resourceGroups/nanod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/nanod2-vm]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.project1[1]: Creation complete after 1m47s [id=/subscriptions/4938xxxxxxx-4edd-8xxxxxxxf78e/resourceGroups/nanod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/nanod1-vm]
╷
│ Error: Error: IP Configuration "nanod0-nic-lb-pool-cfg" was not found on Network Interface "nanod0-nic" (Resource Group "nanod-rg")
│ 
│   with azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[0],
│   on main.tf line 128, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1":
│  128: resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Error: IP Configuration "nanod2-nic-lb-pool-cfg" was not found on Network Interface "nanod2-nic" (Resource Group "nanod-rg")
│ 
│   with azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[2],
│   on main.tf line 128, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1":
│  128: resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Error: IP Configuration "nanod1-nic-lb-pool-cfg" was not found on Network Interface "nanod1-nic" (Resource Group "nanod-rg")
│ 
│   with azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[1],
│   on main.tf line 128, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1":
│  128: resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
```

I do not know this so well to figure out what is going on here. I appreciate all help.

Thank you.

Adding the output of deployment to make it more readable/clear.

```
VmName  ResourceGroupName   Region  VmSize  VirtualNetwork  Subnet  PrivateIpAddress    OsType  PublicIPAddress NicName ApplicationSecurityGroup    OSDiskName  OSDiskCaching   OSDiskSize  DataDiskCount
nanod0-vm   NANOD-RG    eastus  Standard_D2s_v3 nanod-network   nanod-subnet    10.0.2.5    Linux       nanod0-nic      nanod0-OSdisk   ReadWrite   30  0
nanod1-vm   NANOD-RG    eastus  Standard_D2s_v3 nanod-network   nanod-subnet    10.0.2.4    Linux       nanod1-nic      nanod1-OSdisk   ReadWrite   30  0
nanod2-vm   NANOD-RG    eastus  Standard_D2s_v3 nanod-network   nanod-subnet    10.0.2.6    Linux       nanod2-nic      nanod2-OSdisk   ReadWrite   30  0
```

Comment: it deploys all assets including VMs but no public IP addr etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, see the description of the attribute [`azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_backend_address_pool_association#ip_configuration_name):

> `ip_configuration_name` - (Required) The Name of the IP Configuration
> within the Network Interface which should be connected to the Backend
> Address Pool. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

It means the configuration name must exist in the NIC, it's not a new name. So you can try to change the `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association` block like this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
  count               = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].name
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.project1.id
}
```

Comment: I made the change but still getting same error. I destroyed everything and rebuilt it all.

Comment: ╷
│ Error: Error: IP Configuration "nanod1-nic" was not found on Network Interface "nanod1-nic" (Resource Group "nanod-rg")
│ 
│   with azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association.project1[1],
│   on main.tf line 128, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1":
│  128: resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {

Comment: <pre>resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
  count               = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].name  ### "${var.prefix}${count.index}-nic-lb-pool-cfg"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.project1.id
}</pre>

Comment: @rajeev It's my mistake. It should be the configuration name, not nic name, so it's `azurerm_network_interface.example[0].ip_configuration[0].name`. Appologise for my mistake.

Comment: @rajeev Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I want to thanks Charles though it did not work.

The "name" in following:

```
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.project1.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
```

should match the name in following:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "project1" {
  count               = "${var.VMCount > 2 && var.VMCount < 6 ? var.VMCount : 2}"
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.project1[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = "internal"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.project1.id
}
```

once i made that change it worked.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer does not work? Of course, it works well.